# How can i logout from google account when i click my logout button in my android project

Tags: android, google-app-engine

i tried this code in to my project the compiler will show the following error.

this is my code.

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() { @Override public void onResult(Status status) { } });
```

and this is my error

```
cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
```

Comment: please post your full code.@Sat SIva

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
super.onStart();
}

signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
          new ResultCallback<Status>() {
              @Override
              public void onResult(Status status) {
                  // ...
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logged Out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(i);
              }
          });
 }
```

Comment: thank for your response.. i got the output by last prev answer...

Answer (score -1):

i can understand your problem ...

i think you did not implement **GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener** this listener .. and to include this following function in to your java file like..

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

thats it..

if you want more information see this following link
[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect)